# SpriteKit Dashed SKShapeNode Line slow performance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I am developing a game using SpriteKit - Objective C so far so good. I have created a infinity line spawning but I need to make it dashed. I have created the dashed line but the performance is insanely slow I can't even play. My current code is that:

```
    CGFloat pattern[2];
pattern[0] = 20.0;
pattern[1] = 10.0;

CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path,nil,cp1x,cp1y,cp2x,cp2y,p3.x,p3.y);

CGPathRef dashed =
CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath(path,
                              NULL,
                              0,
                              pattern,
                              2);

GameLine* nodea = [GameLine node];
nodea.lineWidth = 4;
nodea.path = dashed;
nodea.startingPoint = startingPosition;
nodea.endingPoint = endingPosition;
nodea.controlPoint1 = CGPointMake(cp1x, cp1y);
nodea.controlPoint2 = CGPointMake(cp2x, cp2y);
nodea.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.f/255.f green:87.f/255.f blue:144.f/255.f alpha:1];
nodea.zPosition = 20;

SKEffectNode* node = [SKEffectNode node];

[node addChild:nodea];
[_world addChild:node];

node.shouldRasterize = YES;
node.shouldEnableEffects = YES;

[_lines addObject:nodea];

CGPathRelease(dashed);
```

I've heard that if I add the SKShapeNode to SKEffectNode problem will be solved but...When I enable the shouldEnableEffects to my SKEffectNode I am getting black background up on top of the line I don't know why, but the performance is good. If I set it to NO I don't have that black background and everything seems fine but the performance is slow. It is lagging. I will appreciate your help guys !